# I need to 1/10 and 1/100 part of percent in kendo ui numeric text box

Tags: kendo-ui, angular-kendo

I need to 1/10 and 1/100 part of percent, but kendo ui numeric text box allows enter a whole percent.
I try to do something like thins:

```
$("#percent").kendoNumericTextBox({
  format: "##.0000 %"
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how you want to manage the value assigned there are two possible solutions.

**Case 1**: If you want that value `12.3456` gets displayed as `12.3456%`, you should do:

```
$("#percent").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "##.0000 \\%",
    decimals: 4,
    value: 12.3456
});
```

**Case 2**: If you want that value `12.3456` gets displayed as `1234.5600%`, you should do:

```
$("#percent").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "p4",
    decimals: 4,
    value: 12.3456
});
```

**Case 3**: If you want that value `12.3456` gets displayed as `1234.56%`, you should do:

```
$("#percent").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "p2",
    decimals: 4,
    value: 12.3456
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/4ab9Z/

Comment: Im using angular-kendo and for me case 1 gives me 1234.56%, how would one go about eliminating the * 100 so that the contents of the numeric text box is representative of the percentage displayed?

Comment: k-format="\'# \\\\%\'"  the double double escape caught me out... ;)